# Numerically solve equation

Tags: equation-solving

I have an equation, that I want to solve numerically. 
The equation is

$$x(1-cx)-\frac{xy}{1+x^{1+\gamma}}=0$$

The problem here is the $\gamma$.
What I want to achieve is a plot of the solutions in the $(x,y,\gamma)$-space. Actually, I want to plot ther borders of the surface, to make the other surfaces visible as well, but this is another issue.
I have a fixed value of $c$ and I realized, that symbolically, this would get quite hard. So my first approach was something like this:

```
$Assumptions = gamma >= 0 && x>=0 && z>=0;
c = 0.1732;
dx := x*(1 - c*x) - x*y/(1 + y^(1 + gamma))
Reap[Do[Sow[NSolve[dx==0,p,Reals]],{gamma,0,1,0.05}]]
```

I get the following error

```
NSolve was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients.
```

Isn't there a simple solution to obtain all positive real solutions for $x$, assuming that $y>= 0$?

Thank you!

Comment: Use `Rationalize` around `c` and the step size to get rid of the message.

Comment: `Reduce[x*(1 - c*x) - x*y/(1 + y^(1 + gamma)) == 0, gamma, Reals]` returns what looks like a legitimate solution fairly quickly

Comment: @user21 This indeed helps to get rid of the method. But I am searching for a solution of some form $x(y,\gamma)$ and I am only getting ```ConditionalExpression``` with this. Any idea?

Comment: @gpap This may be right. But I can't confirm this because I don't know how to plot these expressions.. Any idea on this?

Comment: What's `z`? Do you mean `y`?

Comment: Oh yes, sorry. I will correct that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're only interested in the plot, not the functional form of `x[y, gamma]`, then you can use `ContourPlot3D`:

```
ContourPlot3D[dx == 0, {gamma, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 5}, {x, 0, 1/c},
  AxesLabel -> {gamma, y, x}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Perfect, thank you. Do you, by chance, know whether/how it is possible to plot only the borders of the surfaces?

Comment: @gumpel Sorry, I don't know about plotting the borders only.  Maybe look at `ContourPlot3D` options.